# Keeping Finder in sync with changes made in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

Until Yosemite, I could work in the Terminal and file system changes would be immediately updated in Finder. Now, however, Finder seems to be out of sync with the filesystem. Finder shows files I have moved or deleted as still being in the original folder.

I am at a loss to restore Finder's old behaviour. Things I have tried, to no avail:

- `rm .DS_Store; open .`
- Seeing that my whole Documents folder had become infected with the *com.apple.quarantine* attribute, removing it with `xattr -drv com.apple.quarantine .`
- Checking the filesystem with Disk Utility; no errors reported.

It's not the problem described in [Moving folder to Trash in Finder is not synchronized with Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23882/moving-folder-to-trash-in-finder-is-not-synchronized-with-terminal), as any files I delete, I delete with `rm`.

**Update**: what does work is *Force Quit...* → *Restart Finder*, which is a bit drastic.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily a fix, but I use this to refresh Finder windows - works after changing file visibility too, rather than killing the Finder.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view              
        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat  
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks; I will try this (if I knew what it was … automater? Looks like tcl, but wordy). Not hopeful of it working, though — I can have no finder windows open, then open a new one, and it shows me the file state from several hours ago. It has only started happening in Yosemite.

Comment: It's Applescript. Make it an app or launch it from a key command in Automator etc [I don't use Automator personally so I'm no use on that front]

Comment: Thanks - just as an update, the script doesn't do anything. New files aren't showing unless I restart Finder

Comment: ah, ok; thanks for the heads up. There's something deeper to it then, I guess. it works fine for hiding/showing dot files etc - though the Finder already knows they're there.